# ubuntu 12.04 not loading after GNOME uninstallation

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I'd installed and than uninstalled GNOME desktop environment. Now, my ubuntu 12.04 is not loading at all, it just doesn't go pass the Ubuntu waiting screen after boot load.

However, I am able boot in recovery mode as root(drop to root shell prompt).

I'm still newbie into Linux, please help ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to open tty console from normal mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).
If it works, login with your username and password and get root rights by typing:

```
sudo -s
```

Then, return LightDM by typing

```
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and choosing it from the menu.
It should work (from the login manager change session by clicking the icon next to your username and from the menu choose Ubuntu.